# In Rails when using the Devise Gem how to let only admin register new admins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im using the `Devise` gem for authentications. I have already created an Admin model and added Devise to it. Normally anyone can register. But I need only an Admin to add new Admins to the system. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can found your answer in [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos)

First you should read this [How To: Add an Admin Role](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role), Option 2 is suitable for your case.

Adding an "super admin" attribute to your admin model with boolean type.

```
$ rails generate migration add_super_admin_to_users super_admin:boolean
```

If you're using postgresql/mysql for dbms, Don't forget before migration add default false to `super_admin` attibute

If you have "Super Admin" user on your database, and then you should customize admin registration pages,  [Devise::RegistrationsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). This customize devise regristration controller

```
registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :authenticate_role!

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    your_specific_path
  end

end
```

And add `authenticate_role!` on your `application_controller.rb` looks like

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery


  protected
  def authenticate_role!
    if current_user.super_admin == true
      super
    else
      redirect_to another_path, notice: "You can't access this page"
    end
  end

end
```

Add this to your `views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

```
<div><%= f.label :super_admin %><br />
<%= f.check_box :super_admin %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you go to db under this seed.rb file

you type your details

Role.create(name: 'Admin')

User.create(name: "admin", email: admin@ibc.com", password: "admin", password_confirm: "admin)

ad go to terminal type

$rake db:seed

and check database  fields